How to correctly average percentages?
I'm working with genomics data; percent-spliced-in (psi) values which can be found by the proportion of inclusion counts to exclusion counts. To get the average-psi value for a sample, I was just calculating the mean of the percentages, which I now realize was wrong because they don't come from equal weights.
I'm purely a "computational guy" and not very statistical so I just threw things at it and look at the results.  score2 (average of z-normalized psi) and score4 (geometric mean of psi) works the best in the actual data; I did this by correlating another measurement with the score. I'm hoping and would appreciate ya'll in guiding me the correct way and perhaps explaining why it's correct. Suggestions of more sophisticated methods (maybe Cohen D?) are also welcome. Thank you very much. The actual data is very noisy and large, here's an example of what I've tried in R:
inc <- data.frame(sampleA = c(1755,175 ,11 ,35),
                  sampleB = c(1500,199,15,20),
                  sampleC = c(1768,900,122,60),
                  sampleD = c(1808,881,123,65))

exc <- data.frame(sampleA = c(11311,706 ,257 ,8900),
                  sampleB = c(12000,706,257,8780),
                  sampleC = c(2958,354,257,7000),
                  sampleD = c(2800,354,257,7990))
psi <- inc / (inc + exc)

score1 <- colMeans(psi)
score2 <- colMeans(t(scale(t(psi))))
score3 <- colSums(inc)/(colSums(inc)+colSums(exc))
geometric.mean <- function(x,na.rm=TRUE){exp(mean(log(x),na.rm=na.rm))} 
score4 <- apply(psi, 2, geometric.mean)

```


Hi! I know almost nothing about genomics, but I probably can help with averaging things. Can you explain to me (with words not code), what the things in your example code represent? I am assuming you want some kind of average that places more importance on larger sample sizes?
